# where to download the "ipa file" of "App Store"?

Tags: iphone, app-store

In my opinion, "App Store" is just an ordinary app installed on iPhone.

If so, where to download the `.ipa`  file of the "App Store"?

Thanks.

Comment: App Store is an internal application of iOS Operating System and it cannot be downloaded and strictly secured by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an app

However, it is preinstalled app for each iOS device and it is no way to install/delete it and no "ipa" is available too. This app is protected by iOS operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it's a system app that manages personal data, let it fall in the wrong hands could be a very big problem.